# PostgreSQL: how to install plpythonu extension

Tags: python, linux, postgresql, ubuntu

I'm running PostgreSQL 9.3.1 on Ubuntu 12.04.4.  I'd like to use the plpython language extension but I get an error when I try to use it I get:

`ERROR:  language "plpythonu" does not exist`

When I try to create the extension:

```sql
CREATE EXTENSION plpythonu
```

I get `ERROR: could not access file "$libdir/plpython2": No such file or directory`
After much searching and digging through blog posts, I've tried installing additional packages, and have copied all the plpython files from /usr/share/postgresql/9.1/extension to /opt/bitnami/postgresql/share/extension where PostgreSQL seems to be looking for them. That at least got me to a point at which PostgreSQL actually *sees* the available extensions. When I run:

```sql
SELECT name, default_version, installed_version FROM pg_available_extensions WHERE name LIKE('plpy*')
```

I get :

```
    name    | default_version | installed_version 
------------+-----------------+-------------------
 plpython2u | 1.0             | 
 plpython3u | 1.0             | 
 plpythonu  | 1.0             |
```

There are still no plpython libraries that I can see in `/opt/bitnami/postgresql/lib`. Can anybody help me get through remaining steps to make the extension work? Thanks in advance!

Comment: *I've tried installing additional packages*. Which additional packages exactly?

Comment: *copied all the plpython files from /usr/share/postgresql/9.1/extension to /opt/bitnami/postgresql/share/extension*. Don't do that! You're lucky PostgreSQL has sanity checks to prevent that from loading incompatible modules and possibly corrupting process memory.

Comment: I believe I used `sudo apt-get install postgresql-contrib postgresql-plpython`

Comment: ... and how did you install bitnami PostgreSQL? (Note that 9.3.1 has some *serious bugs*, so you should *promptly upgrade* if you have data in it that you care about).

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You're using a PostgreSQL package from Bitnami, in `/opt`. It's not clear if you installed this with `apt-get` or via an installer script/program, but in either case it's not the same PostgreSQL as what's in the Ubuntu `postgresql` package.

Installing `postgresql-plpython` won't do you any good, because you're installing PL/Python support for a different PostgreSQL install than the one you're actually using.

You'll need to use the same installation method you originally used to install the Bitnami PostgreSQL to add PL/Python support, if it's available. It might not be provided by Bitnami.

Otherwise, if you're not too attached to using Bitnami's PostgreSQL, you could use the recommended packages from http://apt.postgresql.org/ .

Comment: Thanks, Craig.  I checked with the Bitnami community and unfortunately they don't support the PL/Python extension in their stacks yet so I'll do what you suggest.

Comment: This answer need some upgrade for Ubuntu 18 LTS. `sudo apt install postgresql-plpython` do nothing, it say "Package postgresql-plpython is a virtual package provided by: postgresql-plpython-9.6, postgresql-plpython-9.7, ... postgresql-plpython-11`... So, important in the answer to say "how to select the correct one". There aro also python3, another selection problem.

Comment: .. And there are no `apt` option for `"/usr/share/postgresql/12/extension/plpythonu.control"`

Comment: @PeterKrauss That's a component of the PostgreSQL 12 plpython extension. It's unclear how you managed to install PostgreSQL 12 but not have plpython for PostgreSQL 12 available in your repositories. Post a new, separate question.

Answer (score 20):

for `postgres 11.2` (Debian based) I needed to install:

```
apt-get update && apt-get install postgresql-plpython3-11
```

Comment: I used `apt install postgresql-plpython3-12`  on pg 12 and Ubuntu 18.... but on SQL the `CREATE EXTENSION plpythonu;`  say 
ERROR:  could not open extension control file "/usr/share/postgresql/12/extension/plpythonu.control": No such file or directory

Comment: Workingo for `CREATE EXTENSION plpython3u`

Comment: what happens when you are upgrading an older database to PG11 or PG12 with plpythonu functions? Do functions also need to change LANGUAGE from plpythonu to plpython3u?

Comment: Can anyone confirm that not only `CREATE EXTENSION plpython3u` works with this, but also running `CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION return_version()
  RETURNS VARCHAR
AS $$
    import sys
    return sys.version
$$ LANGUAGE plpython3u;`? Since that does not work on Windows, see [PostgreSQL 13 + Python 3.7.9 + plpython3u: 'psql: server closed the connection unexepectedly.' + 'The application has lost the database connection.'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67852675/postgresql-13-python-3-7-9-plpython3u-psql-server-closed-the-connection-u).

Comment: `sudo apt-get update && apt-get install postgresql-plpython3-13` outputs: `... Hit:6 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security InRelease
Reading package lists... Done` and then the errors: `E: Could not open lock file /var/lib/dpkg/lock-frontend - open (13: Permission denied)` and
`E: Unable to acquire the dpkg frontend lock (/var/lib/dpkg/lock-frontend), are you root?`. I could get rid of this only by adding `postgresql-contrib`, see @BrianBlank's answer.

Answer (score 6):

I'm running Raspbian 10 (buster) / Linux raspberrypi 4.19.97-v7+ #1294 and ran the following commands to install PL/Python 3 on PostgreSQL 11.7.

1. Identify which versions are available for install:

```
pi@raspberrypi:~/$ sudo apt-cache search ".*plpython3.*"
postgresql-plpython3-11 - PL/Python 3 procedural language for PostgreSQL 11
```

2. `sudo apt-get install postgresql-contrib postgresql-plpython3-11`
3. `sudo systemctl start postgresql` (or use `enable` to start this at every startup, see [Getting started with PostgreSQL on Linux](https://www.redhat.com/sysadmin/postgresql-setup-use-cases)) on stand-alone Linux or `sudo service postgresql start` (on WSL2).

Else, you would get the error:

```
psql: error: could not connect to server: No such file or directory
        Is the server running locally and accepting
        connections on Unix domain socket "/var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432"?
```

4. `sudo su - postgres`
5. `psql`
6. `CREATE EXTENSION plpython3u;`
7. Verify with command:

```
select * from pg_language;
```

Comment: Can anyone confirm that not only `CREATE EXTENSION plpython3u` and `select * from pg_language;` works with this, but also running `CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION return_version()   RETURNS VARCHAR AS $$     import sys     return sys.version $$ LANGUAGE plpython3u;`? Since the latter does not work on Windows, the two former do, see [PostgreSQL 13 + Python 3.7.9 + plpython3u: 'psql: server closed the connection unexepectedly.' + 'The application has lost the database connection.'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67852675/postgresql-13-python-3-7-9-plpython3u-psql-server-closed-the-connection-u).

Comment: I can confirm this now. I could get the function created (output: `CREATE FUNCTION`) and then I could run `SELECT return_version();` to get the output: `return_version ------------------------------------------ 3.8.10 (default, Jun 2 2021, 10:49:15) + [GCC 9.4.0] (1 row)`!

Comment: I could not find a way to import still to be installed packages, though, see [Linux: How to install a Python package so that it is found by the already working PostgreSQL 13 plpython3u extension?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69013111/linux-how-to-install-a-python-package-so-that-it-is-found-by-the-already-workin). Please answer if you know how.

Answer (score -1):

If you are using psql-16 with Ubuntu you should use this command:

```bash
sudo apt install postgresql-plpython3-16
```

It worked for me.

Comment: If the package is always `postgresql-plpython3-xx` where `xx` is the PostgreSQL major version, I don't think we need an answer for every version. Proposing an edit to one of the other answers clarifyingithe naming convention would be more useful.

Comment: I thought about that too, but I wasn't sure.