# Pl/python and Pl/r extensions in compose-for-postgresql

Tags: postgresql, ibm-cloud, plpython, plr

Good time of the day, wanted to ask if someone knows what is the way to install PostgreSQL extensions (to be exact, pl/r and pl/python) on IBM Bluemix cloud? I am running compose-postgresql database there and when I issue postgresql query such as 'create extension plpythonu' I get an error: 'ERROR:  could not open extension control file "/usr/local/postgres/9.6.6/share/extension/plpythonu.control": No such file or directory'. The same with pl/r. Would be gratefull if someone helps.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26091390/postgresql-how-to-install-plpythonu-extension

Comment: thanks Jim, however I don't think in that bluemix cloud I have direct access to the file system. it can be through some addition configuration, processing directives or something such.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't believe those extensions are available on Compose Postgres.

For the list of available extensions, see here:

- https://help.compose.com/docs/postgresql-extensions

Comment: Thank you very much, Chris! You have resolved the question.

Comment: I have pressed, but ,unfortunately, I don't have enough reputation since I am a newly registered :( They say I need to have at least 15 reputation scores to up/down vote.

Comment: Np.  Thanks anyway!